# Cant get fa-icon aligned vertically with img

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

So I have been breaking my head about how to get these elements to align, I have gotten pretty close, but the svg shape for the unity logo is not willing to budge... Does someone see anything that I am missing?

There will be quite a few elements, most of them images when they dont have an fa-icon, so I am going to need this quite a few times.

```html
<div class="row">
    <fa-icon class="col icon" [icon]="['fab', 'angular']"></fa-icon>
    <fa-icon class="col icon" [icon]="['fab', 'github']"></fa-icon>
    <img class="col" src="./../../../assets/svg/unity-69-logo-svg-vector.svg">
</div>
```

```css
img {
  display: block;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 25px;
}

.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

[image: img]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox...I put that shhh on everything.

I'm guessing/hoping that's a bootstrap 4 row?  Turn the row in to a flex box, set align items center, and I'd strip out the display attributes from img and .icon

```
<div class="row d-flex align-items-center">
    <fa-icon class="col icon" [icon]="['fab', 'angular']"></fa-icon>
    <fa-icon class="col icon" [icon]="['fab', 'github']"></fa-icon>
    <img class="col" src="./../../../assets/svg/unity-69-logo-svg-vector.svg">
</div>
```

Comment: This is going to sound crazy but flexbox is not working. Its not changing anything. I have updated with a better image that might prove more informative

Comment: Try throwing away width/height/margin/padding from icons and images...also it seems to be horizontal alignment you're after...add the class ```.justify-content-between``` to the div.row  ***updated to jc-between not jc-center

Comment: I removed the columns alltogether and that made it work. I do need to make it responsive now. But that seems to have done something.

Comment: Ah shoot I didn't even see those col classes...derp

Comment: I thought having a row and subdividing it into columns was the right way to do it. Im trying to find the way it works.

Comment: You could even do away with the .row class at this point then. Good luck!